# Roboguice Assisted annotation

Tags: android, roboguice, android-testing

I use Roboguice 1.1.2, with guice-no-aop 2.0. I try to use Assisted injection, that requires the @Assisted annotation. My problem is that the guice-2.0-no_aop.jar does not contain the Assisted annotation. Is that right? 
The roboguice wiki claims that I can use assisted injection. Also the guice 2.0 page does not mention this as a missing feature on the no aop version. Any idea?

Comment: Did you add guice-assistedinject-2.0.jar to your libraries?

Comment: No, but I don't see that on the Guice download page, or on the roboguice site. Where is it listed as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guice-assistedinject-2.0.jar is located in the guice-2.0.zip archive.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice20

I didn't see it mentioned in the 2.0 docs but it is in the 3.0 docs:

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/package-summary.html